# How to fade in out an element in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to do a simple fade in fade out effect to a rectangle in Canvas by editing the string rgba. I tried subtracting and adding to an opacity value and then setting the fillStyle function but so far it only seems to fade in very quickly. Any help will be appreciated.

```
var ctx = cv.getContext('2d');
function fadeOutRectangle() {
var opacity = 1, 
  factor = 1,
  increment = .01;

  var steps = 50;
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, ' + opacity + ')';
      ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 300, 300);

      interval = setInterval(function() {
          if(opacity >= 1) {
            factor = -1
          }
          else if(opacity <= 0) {
            factor = 1 ;
          }
          opacity += factor *increment;
          console.log("opacity",opacity);

          ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 200, ' + opacity + ')';
          ctx.fillRect(20,20,150,100);

      }, 1000/steps);
    }
    fadeOutRectangle();
```

Here's the jfiddle as well:

https://jsfiddle.net/dpxjfpgn/

Comment: You need to clear your canvas between each step, otherwise you'll draw the less opaque frames over the already-drawn frames => no real transparency?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21544143/1693593) may be of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var ctx = cv.getContext('2d');
var opacity = 1,
    factor = 1,
    increment = .01;

  var steps = 50, action = 'decrease';
function fadeOutRectangle() {
  var rectWidth = 300;
  var rectHeight = 300;

  interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (action == 'decrease') {
      rectWidth -= 1;
      if (rectWidth < 0) {
        action = 'increase'
      }
    } else {
      rectWidth += 1;
      if (rectWidth > 300) {
        action = 'decrease'
      }
    }
    if (opacity >= 1) {
      factor = -1
        // clearInterval(interval)
    } else if (opacity <= 0) {
      factor = 1;
    }
    opacity += factor * increment;

    // ctx.rect(20,20,150,100);
    //console.log(ctx.fillStyle)
    
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cv.width, cv.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 200, ' + opacity + ')';
    ctx.fillRect(20, 20, rectWidth, 100);
    //ctx.fill();

    // if(i === steps) {
    //     clearInterval(interval);
    // }
  }, 1000/steps);
  // clearInterval(interval)
}
fadeOutRectangle();
```

```html
<canvas width="400" height="400" id="cv"></canvas>
```

clear the canvas using [clearRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect). and then redraw. to fadein increase the width of rectangle, to fadeout decrease the width of rectangle.

Comment: Oh I see, so I need to clear the rect in the loop for it to fade in and out again. Thanks, this helps a lot!